# Haskell: Break a loop conditionally

Tags: loops, haskell, break

I want to break a loop in a situation like this:

```
import Data.Maybe (fromJust, isJust, Maybe(Just))

tryCombination :: Int -> Int -> Maybe String
tryCombination x y 
               | x * y == 20 = Just "Okay"
               | otherwise = Nothing

result :: [String]
result = map (fromJust) $ 
    filter (isJust) [tryCombination x y | x <- [1..5], y <- [1..5]]

main = putStrLn $ unlines $result
```

Imagine, that "tryCombination" is a lot more complicated like in this example. And it's consuming a lot of cpu power. And it's not a evalutation of 25 possibilities, but 26^3.

So when "tryCombination" finds a solution for a given combination, it returns a Just, otherwise a Nothing. How can I break the loop instantly on the first found solution?

Comment: BTW, `map fromJust . filter isJust` is `catMaybes` from `Data.Maybe`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Simple solution: `find` and `join`

It looks like you're looking for [`Data.List.find`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:find). `find` has the type signature

```
find :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a
```

So you'd do something like

```
result :: Maybe (Maybe String)
result = find isJust [tryCombination x y | x <- [1..5], y <- [1..5]]
```

Or, if you don't want a `Maybe (Maybe String)` (why would you?), you can fold them together with [`Control.Monad.join`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join), which has the signature

```
join :: Maybe (Maybe a) -> Maybe a
```

so that you have

```
result :: Maybe String
result = join $ find isJust [tryCombination x y | x <- [1..5], y <- [1..5]]
```

---

## More advanced solution: `asum`

If you wanted a slightly more advanced solution, you could use [`Data.Foldable.asum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Foldable.html), which has the signature

```
asum :: [Maybe a] -> Maybe a
```

What it does is pick out the first `Just` value from a list of many. It does this by using the `Alternative` instance of `Maybe`. The `Alternative` instance of `Maybe` works like this: (import `Control.Applicative` to get access to the `<|>` operator)

```
λ> Nothing <|> Nothing
Nothing
λ> Nothing <|> Just "world"
Just "world"
λ> Just "hello" <|> Just "world"
Just "hello"
```

In other words, it picks the first `Just` value from two alternatives. Imagine putting `<|>` between every element of your list, so that

```
[Nothing, Nothing, Just "okay", Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Just "okay"]
```

gets turned to

```
Nothing <|> Nothing <|> Just "okay" <|> Nothing <|> Nothing <|> Nothing <|> Just "okay"
```

This is exactly what the `asum` function does! Since `<|>` is short-circuiting, it will only evaluate up to the first `Just` value. With that, your function would be as simple as

```
result :: Maybe String
result = asum [tryCombination x y | x <- [1..5], y <- [1..5]]
```

Why would you want this more advanced solution? Not only is it shorter; once you know the idiom (i.e. when you are familiar with `Alternative` and `asum`) it is much more clear what the function does, just by reading the first few characters of the code.

Comment: @Hennes Added a second half with an alternative (heh, get the pun?) solution. Maybe you don't want to use it right away if it's over your head, but it might be a fun (or torturous) read anyway. :)

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question, [find](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.8/20140916-162/base/Data-List.html#v:find) function is what you need. After you get `Maybe (Maybe String)` you can transform it into `Maybe String` with `join`

While `find` is nicer, more readable and surely does only what's needed, I wouldn't be so sure about inefficiency of the code that you have in a question. The lazy evaluation would probably take care of that and compute only what's needed, (extra memory can still be consumed). If you are interested, try to benchmark.

Answer (score 3):

Laziness can actually take care of that in this situation.

By calling `unlines` you are requesting *all* of the output of your "loop"<sup>1</sup>, so obviously it can't stop after the first successful `tryCombination`. But if you only need one match, just use `listToMaybe` (from `Data.Maybe`); it will convert your list to `Nothing` if there are no matches at all, or `Just` the first match found.

Laziness means that the results in the list will only be evaluated on demand; if you never demand any more elements of the list, the computations necessary to produce them (or even see whether there *are* any more elements in the list) will never be run!

This means you often don't have to "break loops" the way you do in imperative languages. You can write the full "loop" as a list generator, and the consumer(s) can decide independently how much of the they want. The extreme case of this idea is that Haskell is perfectly happy to generate and even filter *infinite* lists; it will only run the generation code just enough to produce exactly as many elements as you later end up examining.

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually even `unlines` produces a lazy string, so if you e.g. only read the first line of the resulting joined string you could *still* "break the loop" early! But you print the whole thing here.

Comment: This is the most basic and important answer, OP should start here.

Answer (score 1):

The evaluation strategy you are looking for is exactly the purpose of the `Maybe` instance of [`MonadPlus`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:MonadPlus). In particular, there is the function [`msum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:msum) whose type specializes in this case to

```
msum :: [Maybe a] -> Maybe a
```

Intuitively, this version of `msum` takes a list of potentially failing computations, executes them one after another until the first computations succeeds and returns the according result. So, `result` would become

```
result :: Maybe String
result = msum [tryCombination x y | x <- [1..5], y <- [1..5]]
```

On top of that, you could make your code in some sense agnostic to the exact evaluation strategy by generalizing from `Maybe` to any instance of `MonadPlus`:

```
tryCombination :: MonadPlus m => Int -> Int -> m (Int,Int)
-- For the sake of illustration I changed to a more verbose result than "Okay".
tryCombination x y 
    | x * y == 20 = return (x,y) -- `return` specializes to `Just`.
    | otherwise   = mzero        -- `mzero` specializes to `Nothing`.

result :: MonadPlus m => m (Int,Int)
result = msum [tryCombination x y | x <- [1..5], y <- [1..5]]
```

To get your desired behavior, just run the following:

```
*Main> result :: Maybe (Int,Int)
Just (4,5)
```

However, if you decide you need not only the first combination but all of them, just use the `[]` instance of `MonadPlus`:

```
*Main> result :: [(Int,Int)]
[(4,5),(5,4)]
```

I hope this helps more on a conceptual level than just providing a solution.

PS: I just noticed that `MonadPlus` and `msum` are indeed a bit too restrictive for this purpose, `Alternative` and `asum` would have been enough.